# Access the routerlink data

Tags: angular

I have a routerlink in an anchor tag, and I want to access the value passed. How can I do it?

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, "bob" is the data is being passed to the component when this anchor tag is clicked, so how can I access this value in the component when it loads? Please note that it is a child component of another component therefore route is not used.

Comment: Share router config of this path

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71013698/edit) (it covers input data as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route should work anyway like this:

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
 const debug = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('debug');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the data using the `Activated Route` service of Angular by injecting it into the component you need data in. For example, the anchor is in Component A, and you navigate to Component B where you require the data `Bob`. You can inject the `Acvtivated Route` in Component B and get the param using it

```js
   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
   
   ngOnInit(): void {
          // For Params
       this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            // Should display Bob
            console.log(params);
        });

        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams: Params) => {
            //Should display { debug: true} object
            console.log(queryParams);
        });
    }
}
```